# Why both of them are not equal

Tags: javascript, compare, string-comparison

I wrote the below code

```
const appletId = 5
const applet41Pager = '#pager_s_' + (appletId - 1) + '_' + (appletId - 4)+'_center'
if ("#pager_s_4_l_center" === applet41Pager.toString()) {
  console.log('equal')
} else {
  console.log('false')
}
```

It alerts false. Can anyone help me out to understand why it returns false? What change is required to make it return true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the string on the left it's letter "l" (lowercase "L"), not number "1". Therefore these two strings are not equal.